# c++ error when use parallel_for

Tags: c++, parallel.for

I'm trying to use parallel_for, but I get an error, the code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ppl.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace concurrency;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    parallel_for(size_t(0), 50, [&](size_t i)
    {
        cout << i << ",";
    }

    cout << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "parallel_for" matches the argument list >argument types are: (size_t, int, lambda []void (size_t i)->void

This is only example, I have to use it in bigger project, but first of all I want to understand how to use it properly.

****edit****

i changed the code to:

```
parallel_for(size_t(0), 50, [&](size_t i)
{
    cout << i << ",";
});
```

but still i get the annoying error:
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "parallel_for" matches the argument list argument types are: (size_t, int, lambda []void (size_t i)->void)

Comment: Is that your actual code?  There appear to be some missing parentheses, etc.

Comment: try `parallel_for(size_t(0), size_t(50), [&](size_t i)...);`

Comment: i add parentheses (my mistake...), but again i get errors

Comment: `IntelliSense` messages are NOT compilation error!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`parallel_for` has the prototype

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void parallel_for(
   T first,
   T last,
   F& f,
   const auto_partitioner& _Part = auto_partitioner()
);
```

`T` is deduced from `first` and `last` but you're giving it `size_t` and `int` making `T` ambiguous.

Also, there are other overloaded functions `parallel_for` and MSVC generates a stupid error message in such case.

Solution 1 :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    parallel_for(size_t(0), size_t(50), [&](size_t i)
    {
        cout << i << ",";
    });

    cout << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Solution 2 :

```
parallel_for<size_t>(size_t(0), 50, [&](size_t i)
        {
            cout << i << ",";
        });
```